# Place of stay on my approved ESTA is different to where I'm actually staying due to bad communication. Should I re-apply?

Tags: esta

I recently had my ESTA application approved. However on it I stated I would be staying in my friend's apartment only to discover my friend has relocated me and my girlfriend to a local hotel. Hence, my ESTA application says I'm staying at one location but I will be staying at another.

Will this be an issue?

Should I re-apply for a new ESTA?

Comment: No problem. Just put the new address on your landing card when you arrive.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any issue at all. As you can imagine, this is a pretty common situation. You make your bookings and ESTA request in advance and then you change your plans for some reasons. This doesn't have any impact on your ESTA request validity.

So don't worry!